# find duplicates in multiple list and return the count of duplicates for each list in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

There are multiple lists,

[1,2], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [6,8,9,10] ...

Is there a way to find and count duplicates for each list?
so for lists above, I want to get:

[1,2]   --- 1 duplicate which is 2

[2,3,4] --- 3 duplicates which are 2,3,4

[3,4,5] --- 2 duplicates which are 3, 4

[6,7,8,9] - 0 duplicate

I am thinking that I can find the duplicates, then compare each list against duplicates and get the results.

Is there a better/faster way to do it?
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there's a way to do this.

First, put your lists into a list.

```
list_of_lists = [[1,2], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [6,8,9,10]]
```

Then, figure out all the items you have:

```
all_items = [n for l in list_of_lists for n in l]
```

Then figure out which items are duplicated:

```
duplicates = set([n for n in all_items if all_items.count(n) > 1])
```

Then calculate duplicates for each list:

```
for l in list_of_lists:
    duplicate_count = len([n for n in l if n in duplicates])
    print("Duplicates: ", duplicate_count)
```

Incidentally, I think you want `3` for the second answer, since both 2, 3, and 4 are all duplicated in your lists.

```
Duplicates:  1
Duplicates:  3
Duplicates:  2
Duplicates:  0
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.  Yes, 3 should be the answer.